# Log4j2 locks logfiles on Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, log4j2

I have a `log4j2.xml` configuration that uses a dynamic date for logging. It runs on a `tomcat`.

```
<RollingRandomAccessFile name="TEST" fileName="my-application-${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.txt" filePattern="my-application-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.txt">
  <Policies>
    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy modulate="true"/>
...
```

Problem was that the rolling file did not work and the logger kept logging to the old file. Therefore I'm running the following command at midnight:

```
((org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false)).reconfigure();
```

This updates the `date` timestamp in the log4j2 configuration, so logfiles are now rolling at midnight.

Problem: the *old* files still have a lock! Even though they are not used anymore.

**Question**: how can I force the `LogManager` to also free the old logfiles and close any filehandlers?

Comment: What version of log4j2 do you use? I saw that custom delete options are added in 2.5, see https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#CustomDeleteOnRollover

Comment: I don't want to delete the files, just free the lock (so that eg external jobs could move them to log archive or other tasks). I'm using  `2.5`.

Answer (score 0):

The filePattern you have above is going to resolve to the same file name as the file being logged to. This is going to make rolling over fail for sure.

Comment: Sorry I just forgot to include it here.